# How to properly wait for user input?

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, wait

I've got several `buttons` in my `Activity` and I have to wait until one of them is pressed. I was thinking about something like

```
while(CONDITION_IS_NOT_TRUE);
```

So basically I could change condition in `OnClickListeners` of `buttons`, which means once you press button, code will continue to execute. But is it OK to do it like that? Is there better or more proper way to do it?

I write some of my code to give you idea what I'm trying to do:

```
while(TRUE){
    if(CONDITION_1){
        setContentView(view1);
    else if(CONDITION_2){
        setContentView(view2);
        button.setOnClickListener...
    }

    //Now I need to wait until condition is not true,
    while(CONDITION_IS_NOT_TRUE);

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to post a code sample so that we can see what you're trying to accomplish. Make sure to explain in detail what you want, because as written, the current question seems odd. The whole point of an onClick listener is that the code is already waiting for user input.

Comment: So what you are saying is you start some process which at some point requires user input to be able to contiue whatever it does?

Comment: @user3552052.. Show your code... and what you really meant..

Comment: what do you mean by "I have to wait until one of them is pressed" this is all the logic of event triggering basically your activity waits an event to continue.

Comment: This is called busy waiting. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

Comment: I've added code, sorry guys, thought that it's not necessary for this question.

Answer (score -1):

It is normal event based behaviour to execute code in an onClickListener of a button. I don't understand why you would need your while loop, who will do the busy waiting?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?